# Оставить открытым и закрыть одновременно

Tags: обсуждение, дефект, очередь-проверок, закрытие-вопросов

Странная ситуация. В очереди проверок на закрытие был вопрос:
[Linphone Не компилиться под windows](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/625321/176217)

Я открыл его в новой вкладе и проголосовал за закрытие:

> [image: закрытие]

Потом вернулся на вкладку с проверкой и (случайно) нажал <kbd>Оставить открытым</kbd>. И в истории проверок он таким образом [висит именно так](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/review/close/141390):

> [image: история]

> [image: проверка]

Как-то это всё нелогично, не находите?

Comment: Может время для смены решения дано?

Comment: @Other и что должно произойти когда это время выйдет?

Comment: Согласен с @Qweriy. TTC тут вряд ли существует.

Answer (score 3):

Нет, не находим.

Голос в очереди проверок - это именно голос в ней. И лимит на проверку - тоже в ней. Голоса за закрытие не относятся к очереди проверок.

Оставить открытым означает, что ты дал голос за исключение вопроса из очереди проверок, как нормального. Голос за закрытие в другом месте к проверке никак не привязан, поэтому тут не отображается.

Кстати, где-то тут в хаках было предложение голосовать не из проверки, а открыв вопрос, чтобы таким образом обходить лимит на число проверок.

Comment: Про обход лимита помню. Но там речь о однополярном решении. Тут же ситуация некоторой неопределенности. Это как одновременно проголосовать за и против сообщения.

Comment: @alexolut, ты дал два голоса: 1. закрыть & 2. исключить из очереди. Первый не связан с проверкой, а второй связан, поэтому он и отображается. К тому же, исключение из проверки не сбрасывает голоса, так что первый тоже на месте. Просто он не относится к проверке, поэтому в ней не отображается.

Comment: и какой в этом смысл?

Comment: @alexolut, [передумать можно](//meta.ru.stackoverflow.com/q/1868/178988) :)

Comment: передумать - это отозвать голос. А в текущей форме это какая-то глупость получается, имхо.